# Switch to my app from system overlay view

Tags: android

I have made a system overlay Icon similar to the one here: https://github.com/mollyIV/ChatHeads
I want it to open my app using the click listener of the icon. I am able to make it open `MainActivity` using `context.startActivity(intent)` with `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`. 
But I would like to open my app as if it was opened from the task switcher(Whatever activity is open, in the same state). How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You are using FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK

> If set, this activity will become the start of a new task on this
>   history stack.

Try to use FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP:

> If set, the activity will not be launched if it is already running at
>   the top of the history stack.

Source: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html